# display tooltip with css only

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I want to have a tooltip on `input:focus` so what I have:

Code:

```css
.containerTooltipXxx{
    padding: 20px; 
    position: relative;
  float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid lime;
    margin: 50px;
}

.hovTol1{display: none;}

.containerTooltipXxx:hover > .hovTol1{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:-5px;
    left: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerTooltipXxx">
    <p class="hovTol1">Tooltip description is here</p>
    <div class="blocks">
      <label>Field</label>  <input></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works great when hover over containerTooltipXxx div but I need to show that tooltip when input is focused so I've tried something like:

```css
.containerTooltipXxx input:focus> .hovTol1{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:-5px;
    left: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

but is not working so if someone can help me with this, Thank you.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMfvx/194/)**

Comment: any harm in using js ?

Comment: @Let's Code  No need for js  :) is very simple but I don't find the perfect combination :)

Comment: http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html

Comment: @falguni that tooltip js is buggy because he create a div with that tooltip but not delete it, however I don't need to use a js for that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would place the tooltip after the input field (in the html) and then use the adjacent selector (`+`):

```
.containerTooltipXxx input:focus + .hovTol1 {}
```

```css
.containerTooltipXxx{
    padding: 20px; 
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid lime;
    margin: 50px;
}

.hovTol1{display: none;}

.containerTooltipXxx input:focus + .hovTol1{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:-5px;
    left: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerTooltipXxx">
  <div class="blocks">
    <label>Field</label>  <input></input>
    <p class="hovTol1">Tooltip description is here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- hover section with green border to see the tooltip-->
```

Comment: it is possible to do that without changing html hierarchy ?  in my local code I cannot insert that paragraph inside div :(

Comment: unfortunately, you need to insert the paragraph somewhere after the input field, so that they are siblings. If you would use an editable div instead of an input element, you could also put the tooltip into this div or use an `:after` or `:before` pseudo-object for the tootip, but `before` and `after` again unfortunately can not be used with input objects. So unless you can adjust the html a little, you will not be able to style the tooltip according to the focused input field only with CSS.